# Entity Framework 5 adding existing entity to nested collection

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, c#-5.0

I've been trying to take advantage of a new way of creating many-to-many relationships - [nice article about EF 5 many-to-many relationships](https://henriquesd.medium.com/entity-framework-core-5-0-many-to-many-relationships-52c6c8b07b6e).

The article states that you no longer need to define relation class and the framework does the job for you.

However, for a couple of hours now I've been struggling to add an existing entity to the collection of another entity.

My models

```cs
public record Bottle
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]   
    public string Username { get; set; }

    // some other properties

    public Collection<User> Owners { get; set; }
}

public record User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // some other properties

    public Collection<Bottle> Bottles { get; set; }
}
```

Say that I want to add a new bottle to the database. I also know owners of that bottle. I had thought that this bit of code could work:

```cs
public async Task<int> AddBottle(BottleForAddition bottle)
{
    var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);
    bottleEntity.Owners = bottle
        .OwnerIds // List<int>
        .Select(id => new User { Id = id })
        .ToCollection(); // my extension method

    var createdEntity = await context.AddEntityAsync(bottleEntity);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return createdEntity.Entity.Id;
}
```

but sadly it does not work (`BottleForAddition` is DTO with almost the same properties).

I get this error:

> Unable to create bottle (error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Users.Username'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
> at ...

So I came up with this

```cs
public async Task<int> AddBottle(BottleForAddition bottle)
{
    var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);
    bottleEntity.Owners = (await context.Users
        .Where(u => bottle.OwnerIds.Contains(u.Id))
        .ToListAsync())
        .ToCollection();

    var createdEntity = await context.AddEntityAsync(bottleEntity);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return createdEntity.Entity.Id;
}
```

That works but I have to fetch `User`s from the database.

Do you know about a better way how to deal with it?

Comment: Added an answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching the Users is generally the correct course of action. This allows you to make the associations but also helps validate that the reference IDs passed from the client are valid. Fetching entities by ID is generally quite fast, so I'd consider avoiding `async`/`await` for this operation. `async` is suited for large or high-frequency operations where server responsiveness could be "hung up". Using it everywhere just leads to slower operations overall.

EF will want to use proxies for navigation properties both for lazy loading (not to be relied on as a crutch, but useful to avoid errors as a worst-case) as well as for change tracking.

```
public record Bottle
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]   
    public string Username { get; set; }

    // some other properties

    public virtual ICollection<User> Owners { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

then in the applicable code...

```
var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);
var users = context.Users
    .Where(u => bottle.OwnerIds.Contains(u.Id))
    .ToList();

foreach(var user in users)
    bottleEntity.Users.Add(user);

// Or since dealing with a new Entity could do this...
//((List<User>)bottleEntity.Users).AddRange(users);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

return bottleEntity.Id;
```

It might be tempting to just create the users and attach them to the DbContext and much of the time this would work, except if there is ever the possibility that the DbContext might have been tracking an instance of any of those to-be-attached users, which will result in a runtime error that an entity with the same ID is already being tracked.

```
var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);

var proxyUsers = bottle.OwnerIds
    .Select(x => new User { Id = x }).ToList();

foreach(var user in proxyUsers)
{
    context.Users.Attach(user);
    bottleEntity.Users.Add(user);
}
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

return bottleEntity.Id;
```

This requires either turning off all entity tracking or remember to always query entities with `AsNoTracking` which can lead to additional work and intermitted bugs appearing if this isn't adhered to consistently. To deal with possible tracked entities is a fair bit more work:

```
var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);

var proxyUsers = bottle.OwnerIds
    .Select(x => new User { Id = x }).ToList();
var existingUsers = context.Users.Local
    .Where(x => bottle.OwnerIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
var neededProxyUsers = proxyUsers.Except(existingUsers, new UserIdComparer()).ToList();
foreach(var user in neededProxyUsers)
    context.Users.Attach(user);


var users = neededProxyUsers.Union(existingUsers).ToList();

foreach(var user in users)
    bottleEntity.Users.Add(user);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

return bottleEntity.Id;
```

Any existing tracked entity needs to be found and referenced in place of an attached user reference. The other caveat of this approach is that the "proxy" users created for non-tracked entities are *not* complete user records so later code expecting to get User records from the DbContext could receive these attached proxy rows and result in things like null reference exceptions etc. for fields that were not populated.

Hence, fetching the references from the EF DbContext to get the relatable entities is generally the best/simplest option.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `Users` table in the database has a `Username` field  does not allow `NULL`
2. You are creating new `User` entities from the `OwnerIds` which doesn't have `Username` value set
3. EF is trying to insert a new user to the `Users` table

Combining the pieces of information above, you'll get a clear picture why the error message says -

> SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Users.Username'.

Then comes the real question, why EF is trying to insert new users at all. Obviously, you created the `User` entities from the `OwnerIds` to add already existing users to the list, not to insert them.

Well, I'm assuming that the `AddEntityAsync()` method you are using (I'm not familiar with it) is an extension method, and inside it, you are using the `DbContext.Add()` or `DbSet<TEntity>.Add()` method. Even if that is no the case, apparently `AddEntityAsync()` at least works similarly as them.

The `Add()` method causes the entity in question (`Bottle`) and all it's related entities (`Users`) present in the entity-graph to be marked as `Added`. An entity marked as `Added` implies - `This is a new entity and it will get inserted on the next SaveChanges call.` Therefore, with your first approach, EF tried to insert the `User` entities you created. See details - [`DbSet<TEntity>.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?view=efcore-5.0)

In your second approach, you fetched the existing `User` entities first. When you fetch existing entities using the `DbContext`, EF marks them as `Unchanged`. An entity marked as `Unchanged` implies - `This entity already exists in the database and it might get updated on the next SaveChanges call.` Therefore, in this case the `Add` method caused only the `Bottle` entity to be marked as `Added` and EF didn't try to re-insert any `User` entities you fetched.

As a general solution, in a disconnected scenario, when creating new entity with an entity-graph (with one or more related entities) use the `Attach` method instead. The `Attach` method causes any entity to be marked as `Added` only if it doesn't have the primary-key value set. Otherwise, the entity is marked as `Unchanged`. See details - [`DbSet<TEntity>.Attach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.attach?view=efcore-5.0)

Following is an example -

```
var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);
bottleEntity.Owners = bottle
    .OwnerIds // List<int>
    .Select(id => new User { Id = id })
    .ToCollection(); // my extension method

await context.Bottles.Attach(bottleEntity);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Not related to the issue :**
Also, since you are already using `AutoMapper`, if you define your `BottleForAddition` DTO as something like -

```
public class BottleForAddition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    // some other properties

    public Collection<int> Owners { get; set; }     // the list of owner Id
}
```

then you will be able to configure/define your maps like -

```
this.CreateMap<BottleForAddition, Bottle>();

this.CreateMap<int, User>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s));
```

which could simplify the operation code like -

```
var bottleEntity = mapper.Map<Bottle>(bottle);

await context.Bottles.Attach(bottleEntity);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```